# CSS display image on two columns (column-count seperated)

Tags: image, css

I have a div that is seperated in 2 columns, using:

```
column-count: 2;
column-gap: 20px;
```

Inside of that i do now have an image: http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/6710/herpt.png
I want this image to be on both columns, so i tried with

```
    column-span:all
```

http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/8664/derpv.png , but this destroys the text flow, its now two blocks with columns, one above and one below the image, but i would like to keep the usual flow and seperate the single columns.

Comment: Well, my first remark is that you're going to get a solution that isn't cross-browser compatible, since these CSS3 attributs don't work in all browsers (even some modern ones). That being said, so long as you provide some graceful degradation, you should be in good shape. Check out http://w3fools.com/, I know that they use it for their "Quiz Answers" section.

Answer (score 0):

That's what `column-span`, as it is [defined](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#column-span), is supposed to do:

> **Example XX**
>
> In this example, an h2 element has
>   been added to the sample document
>   after the first sentence in the fourth
>   sentence (i.e., after the word
>   "jkl."). This styling applies:
>
> ```
> h2 { column-span: all; background: silver }  
> img { display: none }
> ```
>
> By setting ‘column-span’ to ‘all’, all
>   content that appear before the h2
>   element is shown before the h2
>   element.

What you need for this is [CSS3 Exclusions](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-exclusions/) or [CSS3 Positioned floats](http://www.interoperabilitybridges.com/css3-floats/).  Unfortunately, no released browsers yet support either (and it's likely that the two specs will be merged before browsers start adding support).

Adobe has a [prototype WebKit based implementation of Regions and Exclusions](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/cssregions.html) you can try things out in.  If you have IE10 Developer Preview 2, [there's a demo of positioned floats available here](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/PositionedFloats/Default.html).